# ArcMap 10.1 Slow Performance with VB.NET Code (Spatial Query)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, select-by-location, vb.net, spatial-query, visual-studio

We have just installed ArcGIS 10.1 and MS Visual Studio 10 (Dot Net Framework 3.5) to develop automation tools for *Select by Attribute* and *Select by Location* using VB.Net.

We developed a new add-in button in ArcMap which runs Spatial Query on FGDB Geodatabase. The Target Layer (Polyline) includes 700,000+ features, and the Source Layer (Polygon) includes 200,000+ features.
First we run Attribute query which selects 20,000+ features from the Source Layer, and then we run Spatial Query. using the "Select by Location" built-in tool in ArcMap takes ~1.5 mins; however, using the below code takes ~6.5 mins. After Debugging,  more than 5.5 mins is delayed in the following line of code:

```
pTrgtFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures(TryCast(pSFilter, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter), SelectionType, False)
```

It is very critical performance issue, and I need to select the features in that layer in order to perform additional queries (attribute & spatial).

We are also trying to find another way/method than "SelectFeatures" to select the features in the Target layer, however still not sure if there is.

Suffering from very slow performance when using our code to perform the spatial queries.

Hereafter is the used code:

```
Public Function p_GenSelectByLocation(ByVal SourceLayerName As String, ByVal TargetLayerName As String, ByVal Whereclause As String, ByVal SelectionType As esriSelectionResultEnum, ByVal RelationType As esriSpatialRelEnum) As Integer
    Try
        Dim pboolSrcFound As Boolean = False
        Dim pboolTrgtFound As Boolean = False
        Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer = My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.FocusMap.Layers(Nothing, True)
        Dim pSrcFLayer As IFeatureLayer = Nothing
        Dim pTrgtFLayer As IFeatureLayer = Nothing
        Dim pLoopLayer As ILayer = pEnumLayer.Next()


        pEnumLayer.Reset()
        Do Until pLoopLayer Is Nothing
            If TypeOf pLoopLayer Is IFeatureLayer Then
                If pLoopLayer.Name = SourceLayerName Then
                    pSrcFLayer = pLoopLayer
                    pboolSrcFound = True
                End If

                If pLoopLayer.Name = TargetLayerName Then
                    pTrgtFLayer = pLoopLayer
                    pboolTrgtFound = True
                End If
            End If
            If pboolSrcFound = True And pboolTrgtFound = True Then Exit Do
            pLoopLayer = pEnumLayer.Next()
        Loop
        If pSrcFLayer Is Nothing Or pTrgtFLayer Is Nothing Then Exit Try

        Dim pSrcFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection = pSrcFLayer
        Dim pGeomToUnion As IGeometryCollection = New GeometryBag()

        If pSrcFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count = 0 Then Exit Try

        'Get union of Geometry of all selected features
        Dim pCursor As ICursor = Nothing
        pSrcFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pCursor)

        If pCursor Is Nothing Then Exit Try
        Dim pfeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor = pCursor

        Dim pFeature As IFeature = pfeatureCursor.NextFeature
        Dim pGeometry As IGeometry
        pGeometry = pFeature.Shape

        Dim pCount As Integer = 0
        Do Until pFeature Is Nothing
            pCount += 1
            pGeometry = pFeature.Shape
            pGeomToUnion.AddGeometry(pGeometry)
            pFeature = pfeatureCursor.NextFeature
        Loop

        Dim pEnumGeometry As IEnumGeometry = pGeomToUnion
        'Dim pgeometrybag As IGeometryBag = pEnumGeometry

        Dim pResultGeom As ITopologicalOperator = Nothing
        If pGeometry.GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline Then
            pResultGeom = New Polyline
            pResultGeom.ConstructUnion(pEnumGeometry)
        ElseIf pGeometry.GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon Then
            pResultGeom = New Polygon
            pResultGeom.ConstructUnion(pEnumGeometry)
        End If

        If pResultGeom Is Nothing Then Exit Try

        'define the spatial filter and select the features based on the union Geometry
        Dim pSFilter As ISpatialFilter = New SpatialFilter


        'If pTrgtFLayer Is Nothing Then Exit Try
        Dim pnameOfShapeField As System.String = pTrgtFLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName
        pSFilter.GeometryField = pnameOfShapeField
        pSFilter.Geometry = TryCast(pResultGeom, IGeometry)
        pSFilter.SpatialRel = RelationType

        Dim pTrgtFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection = pTrgtFLayer
        pTrgtFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures(TryCast(pSFilter, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter), SelectionType, False)

        Return pTrgtFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count

    Catch ex As Exception
        pFuncReturnDebug(ex)
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to focus on a single query, reporting details about the datasets and their spatial and attribute indexes, and the exact timings involved. It's unlikely anyone here is still using an ancient 10.1 build, so reproducing your issue is likely to be a challenge.

Comment: You give no indication what your data source types are or how many selected features there are or what the data is and the complexity of the data. Do you have a million polygons selected that represent boundaries of geology across the entire Amazon basin? If so don't be surprised it's slow.  Edit your question and provide this information.

Comment: Edits were done

Comment: Additionally, and after investigation, when we change the esriSelectionResultEnum from "Add to Selection" to"New", the performance increased 6 times (~1min). Thus, to narrow down the perfromance issue, it seems related to "Add to selection" option. However, the query requires this option.  Any Advise!

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling the issue is to do with the geometry in your spatial filter. You build this by `ConstructUnion`. This according to your update can be over 200,000 polygons.

Think about what it is creating, a mega-sized polygon composed of possibly millions of vertices, almost certainly multi-part, covering much of the extent of your data. This will negate the influence of a spatial index as you created a geometry that will likely be in all areas of your data with respects to your target layer. So something that is everywhere needs to be tested against everything. Hence poor performance.

Try doing your initial attribute selection, do not attempt to union the geometries. Loop over the selection doing an additive select `esriSelectionResultAdd` in `IFeatureSelection`? See if you get better performance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I may understand that I should Loop over each selected feature in the source layer (count 20,000+) and add feature to the feature selection in the Target layer based on esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelContains. I will try this scenario and post my results here.